# Default Browser Options

Tags: microsoft-edge

Is it possible to have app open in a different browser than my default edge? My email app won't totally open in edge but opens totally with Firefox. I'd like to use Firefox just for that app.

Comment: Can you right click on the app and open with Firefox?  If so, that is the best way I know to handle two browsers

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “app”? Sounds like you’re talking about a web application. How do you start it? Did you create a shortcut or something like that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, you can pass a URL as an argument to a executable in a shortcut. This is pretty well documented online. Look for "make shortcut to open site in (browser)".

Answer (score 1):

Copy your shortcut to Firefox (or create a new one). Right click the shortcut and chose `Properties`. On the first tab, the `Target:` textbox will be filled with something similar to "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", you have to add `"-url URL_TO_YOUR_APP"` to it. Eg `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -url https://www.outlook.com"`. This way it will always open with firefox.